# Django CreateView object.id in get_succes_url pk(id) is NONE and then after redirecting to another URL it prints out created entry ID

Tags: python, django, django-forms, detailview, create-view

I have a problem that I just can't figure out.
After creating a work order I want to redirect to the detail page of that work order.
Here is my models.py

```
class Radni_nalozi(models.Model):
    Klijent = models.ForeignKey(Klijenti, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Pacijent = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Rok_isporuke = models.DateField()
    Cijena = models.FloatField(default=0)
    Napomene = models.CharField(max_length=400,blank=True)
    Zaduzenja = models.CharField(max_length=400,blank=True)
    Status = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default = "OTVOREN")
    Aktivan = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
       return f"{self.id} - {self.Klijent}, {self.Pacijent}"
```

And here is my model form:

```
class RadniModelForm(BSModalModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Radni_nalozi
        fields = ["Klijent","Pacijent","Rok_isporuke","Napomene","Zaduzenja"]
        labels = {"Klijent":"Klijent: ", "Pacijent":"Pacijent: ", "Rok_isporuke":"Rok isporuke: ", "Napomene":"Napomene: ","Zaduzenja":"Zaduženja: "}
        widgets = {'Rok_isporuke': DatePickerInput(options={
                        "locale":"en-gb",
                    })}
```

I want to create a new work order and I'm using django BSModalCreateView.
Here is my views.py:

```
class RadniCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,BSModalCreateView):
    template_name = 'app/radni_nalozi/dodaj_rn.html'
    form_class = RadniModelForm


    def get_form(self):
        form = super(RadniCreateView,self).get_form() #instantiate using parent
        form.fields['Klijent'].queryset = Klijenti.objects.filter(Aktivan=1)
        return form

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BSModalCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = 'NOVI RADNI NALOG'
        context['gumb'] = 'KREIRAJ'
        return context

    def get_success_url(self):
        print(self.object.pk)
        return reverse_lazy('detalji_rn', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
```

Here is urls.py:

```
path('radni_nalozi', views.Radni_nalozi_view.as_view(), name='radni_nalozi'),
    path('radni_nalozi_arhiva', views.Radni_nalozi_arhiva_view.as_view(), name='radni_nalozi_arhiva'),
    path('dodaj_rn', views.RadniCreateView.as_view(), name='dodaj_rn'),
    path('radni_nalozi/details_rn/<pk>', views.RadniDetailView.as_view(), name="detalji_rn"),
    path('radni_nalozi/update/<pk>', views.RadniUpdateView.as_view(), name="update_rn"),
    path('radni_nalozi/delete/<pk>', views.RadniDeleteView.as_view(), name="delete_rn"),
```

The command print(self.object.pk) returns NONE although the object is created. If I put some other hardcoded value in reverse_lazy function (for example number 13) then my view executes, it redirects to the hardcoded value and prints out command *print(self.object.pk)* two times, first with value NONE and then with the value of just created entry?

How can I access the pk of the created entry before the view is redirected so I could redirect to a detail page of that created entry (work order)?

EDIT dodaj_rn.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/forma_add.css' %}">
<div class="container novi_rn">

  <form method="post" action="" class="js-quote-request-form form_dodavanje"" id="quoteForm">
    {% csrf_token %}


   <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title">{{ title }}</h4>
      <!-- <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button> -->
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">

      {% for field in form %}
        <div class="form-group{% if field.errors %} invalid{% endif %}">
          <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
          {{ field }}
          {% for error in field.errors %}
            <p class="help-block">{{ error }}</p>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
      <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button> -->
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">{{ gumb}}</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

EDIT JS script for triggering modal form for creating new entry:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#create-rn").modalForm({
        formURL: "{% url link %}"
    });

});
</script>
```

EDIT: This is my forms.py for RadniModelForm. After I changed BSModalModelForm to forms.ModelForm and BSModalCreateView to only CreateView, now the entry is created and I get an object.id but the view won't redirect to a detail page. I get errors in the console that you can see in the bottom.

```
class RadniModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Radni_nalozi
        fields = ["Klijent","Pacijent","Rok_isporuke","Napomene","Zaduzenja"]
        labels = {"Klijent":"Klijent: ", "Pacijent":"Pacijent: ", "Rok_isporuke":"Rok isporuke: ", 
                  "Napomene":"Napomene: ","Zaduzenja":"Zaduženja: "}
        widgets = {'Rok_isporuke': DatePickerInput(options={
                        "locale":"en-gb",
                    })}
```

EDIT: When I changed RadniCreateView class from BSModalCreateView to CreateView and RadniModelForm class from BSModalModelForm to ModelForm (not forms.ModelForm) the redirecting works. But the new entry is created two times, and the view redirects me to the last one.

Comment: Pozdrav! Can you add urls.py please? Normally you can get the `pk` through `self.kwargs['pk']` if your `pk` is mentioned in the URL.

Comment: To me it looks like the only culprit could be the JS code which creates the AJAX request.  If you take a look at the code of the lib you're using (https://github.com/trco/django-bootstrap-modal-forms/blob/master/bootstrap_modal_forms/mixins.py#L37), if your request is malformed (not ajax) the form will be saved with `commit=False`, therefore, the pk will not be generated yet. Could you add the JS code, too?

Comment: I think it could be fixed by adding the `updateAsync` param in your JS. See https://github.com/trco/django-bootstrap-modal-forms/blob/master/examples/templates/index.html#L145

Comment: I used a simple JS script to trigger modal window. I added the script to my original question. Where do I need to add updateAsync?

Comment: Well, in the same place as `formURL`, add `updateAsync: true`. Check the link in my previous comment for an example.

Comment: I tried that already, but stil I get the following error:
if not is_ajax(self.request.META) or self.request.POST.get('asyncUpdate') == 'True':
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'META'

Comment: I updated my original question with the latest update. Please check and help if you can. Thanks!

Comment: This error comes from the code of `BSModalModelForm`, so did you actually change this class?

Comment: You were right. I changed a form class to the wrong one. But now I get a different problem. So I changed RadniCreateView class from BSModalCreateView to CreateView and RadniModelForm class from BSModalModelForm to ModelForm and now redirecting works, but the problem is that the new entry is created two times and the view redirects me to the last one. Any idea why is this happening? If I add AsyncUpdate: true then I get errors, but without AysncUpdate it is working, but the entry is created two times.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the library you're using for Ajax. Try deleting the JS code for modal forms.

Comment: If I use normal form then it works. But I need it to be a ModalForm. Don't know what else to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

Ok, I understand the problem now. Your library is working with modals. So, urls and templates of "createview" and "updateview" are auxiliary for the proper functioning of modals. With this library, It has no sense the "success_url" because the idea of a modal is to be integrated in a parent template.

If you want to redirect your user to another url different from the original one, change the class of "RadniCreateView":

From this:

```
class RadniCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,BSModalCreateView):
```

To this:

```
class RadniCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
```

OLD ANSWER:

It seems that when get_success_url() is called the object cannot be obtained. I don't see any errors in the code, but I don't understand the usefulness of this line:

```
context = super(BSModalCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

By changing the super() of the context you may be looking for the object in the wrong class. Maybe it works if you change it for this one:

```
context = super(RadniCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it doesn't help.

Comment: I can't find anything wrong. Can you share the code of "dodaj_rn.html"?

Comment: Okay, I tried to change BSModalCreateView to just CreateView and then new entry is no longer created and I get the following error:

if not is_ajax(self.request.META) or self.request.POST.get('asyncUpdate') == 'True':
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'META'

I also added JS script for triggering modal form for creating RN in original question.

Comment: Okay, I changed RadniCreateView class from BSModalCreateView to CreateView and RadniModelForm class from BSModalModelForm to ModelForm and now redirecting works, but the problem is that the new entry is created two times and the view redirects me to the last one. Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: Probably you are sending the form twice. The "normal one" with the submit button and another with your javascript. Check your javascript code and search if there is a submit() function

Comment: If I use normal form then it works. But I need it to be a ModalForm. Don't know what else to try.